# Is it possible to find a formula for $d$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are complex numbers on the unit circle, and $\overline{ab}\perp\overline{cd}$, is it possible to find a formula for $d$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: There are multiple perpendicular secants (just move the line parallel to the fixed secant).

Comment: @nishant No, $a, b, c$ are fixed. This makes $d$ unique.

Comment: Oh, that's true. But the original commenter seemed to imply that there was a unique perpendicular secant and thus that both $c$ and $d$ are unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Chords $AB$ and $CD$ are perpendicular if and only if

$$ \stackrel{\frown}{AC} + \stackrel{\frown}{BD} = \stackrel{\frown}{CB} + \stackrel{\frown}{DA} $$

Hence, if you let $ a = e^{i \alpha}, b = e^{i \beta}, c = e^{i \gamma}, d = e^{i \delta}$, what can you say about $ \delta$ in terms of the rest?

Comment: Does anyone know the command to get an arc? \widearc and \overarc do not work.

Comment: \stackrel{\frown}{AB}

Comment: @asdf Thanks!   ..